# How to use application.properties file in spring boot Gradle project

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, manifest

Having a Manifest.yml file as like below sample -

```
application:
-name:

Env :
  URL: google.com
  PWD : abcxyz
```

How can I retrieve and utilise the values of url and PWD inside a normal java class?

Normally, I would get values from manifest.yml through application.property file.

I'm not clear how to do the same in Gradle project as there is no src/main/resources folder or application.property file in newly created Gradle project.

Comment: You need to provide more information, e.g. examples of how you did it with Maven, because I can't figure out if you're talking about properties for Maven to use, or properties for the Java program to use, and if so, what Maven has to do with that.

Comment: Sorry I got confused. I wanted to get some property values from pivotal cloud foundry into my Gradle project and use those in my application.

Comment: So you want your build script to build the `application.properties` file? --- *"How to do **the same** in Gradle project"* What "same" are you talking about? Are you referring to "spring boot project"? How did it do it? What build tool was it using? Very confusing, since Spring Boot projects can be done with Maven, Gradle, *and* Ant, so saying "Spring Boot project" doesn't say much.